# Explicit and implicit Euler's methods of a heat transfer PDE

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, pde

I have been experimenting a bit with an explicit and implicit Euler's methods to solve a simple heat transfer partial differential equation:

∂T/∂t = alpha * (∂^2T/∂x^2)

*T* = temperature, *x* = axial dimension. The initial condition (I.C.) I used is for x = 0, T = 100 °C. And the boundary condition (B.C.) at the end of the computational grid: for *T*(x = L) = *T*(x = L-1), where *L* is a length of the computational grid -> the last and the and next-to-last values of temperature are the same.

**Explicit method (works fine)**: Every values of *T* are calculated by `T1(i) + heat_coefficient*((T1(i+1)-2*T1(i)+T1(i-1))/dx^2)*dt`, except for the first and the last value which are specified by the I.C. and B.C., respectively.

***My question:***
**Implicit method**: At first, I create a tri-diagonal matrix `MAT`, which defines a relationship between the values in the next time line (*n+1*). In the case of an implicit method, I cannot write I.C. and B.C. exactly, and therefore I save them on the “Right side of the equation”, i.e. `pS(i) = -(T2(i)*dx^2)/(heat_coefficient*dt);`

By this, I express all the values in one time line (*n*) and after that, I continue in the following time line (*n+1*).

If I put I.C. or B.C. into the “Right side of the equation”, the results become very sensitive to any change of positional (*dx*) and time (*dt*) step. Behavior of the temperature function is therefore wrong: the curves of a temperature should converge to the same values after certain time (if the time goes to infinity), however, my curves converge to a different values (and randomly change based on *dx* and *dt*).

How do I achieve to start at a temperature of 100 °C, such that after an “infinitely” long time, all of the temperature curves converge to 100 °C?

Should the values of I.C. and B.C. be put into a tri-diagonal matrix - e.g., if I have matrix with dimensions [N,N], then I specify I.C. for point [1,1], and B.C. for point [N,N]? (Unfortunately, it did not work properly when I tried)

Also, my implementation of the tri-diagonal matrix is probably not very nice, but it works.

Here is my code:

```
% Heat transfer numerical solution test
% Implicit and explicit formula

function Temperature
  clear all
  clc
  
  heat_coefficient = 0.03;
  
  dt    = 0.0001; % time step (s)
  dx    = 0.01; % positional step (m)
  time   = 1; % (s)
  length = 0.5 % (m)
  t_count = fix(time/dt) % number of time nodes
  x_count = fix(length/dx) % number of positional nodes
  
  T1  = zeros(x_count,1); % Explicit method
  T2  = zeros(x_count,1); % Implicit method
  pS  = zeros(x_count,1); % Implicit method (right side of the equation, constant value)
  MAT = zeros(x_count,x_count); % Tri-diagonal matrix - for implicit method
  
  curve_count = 10; % Number of curves that are plotted
  time_count = 0; % Time cycle count
  
  % Tri-diagonal matrix diagonals specification
  A = 1;
  B = -(dx^2/(heat_coefficient*dt) + 2); % Main diagonal
  C = A;
  
  for j=1:t_count % Cycle over time nodes
      
      for i=1:x_count % Cycle over positional nodes
          
          if i == 1
            T1(i) = 100; % Initial condition for explicit method
            T2(i) = 100; % Initial condition for implicit method
            MAT(i,i) = B;
            MAT(i,i+1) = C;
            
          elseif i == x_count
            T1(i) = T1(i-1); % B.C. for explicit method (last equals the next-to-last)
            T2(i) = T2(i-1); % B.C. for implicit method (last equals the next-to-last)
            MAT(i,i-1)= A; 
            MAT(i,i) = B;
            
          else
            % Euler's explicit discretization
            T1(i) = T1(i) + heat_coefficient*((T1(i+1)-2*T1(i)+T1(i-1))/dx^2)*dt; 
            
            % Implicit method - creation of tri-diagonal matrix
            MAT(i,i-1)=A;
            MAT(i,i)  =B;
            MAT(i,i+1)=C;
          end
          
          % Right side of the equation
          pS(i) = -(T2(i)*dx^2)/(heat_coefficient*dt);
          
          
      end
      
      %  PDEs, function
      T2 = EQsystem(MAT,pS);
      
      % Condition to plot only a certain number of temperature curves
      if fix(j/(t_count/curve_count)) == j/(t_count/curve_count)
         if time_count == 0
             y_out1 = T1;
             y_out2 = T2;
             time_count = time_count + 1;
         else
             y_out1 = [y_out1 T1];
             y_out2 = [y_out2 T2];
             time_count = time_count + 1;
         end
      end
      
  end
  
  x = linspace(0, length, x_count); % Nodes along the axial axis
  % Graph
  subplot(2,1,2); 
  plot(x, y_out1); % Explicit
  title('Explicit')
  subplot(2,1,1); 
  plot(x, y_out2); % Implicit
  title('Implicit')
  
end

function x=EQsystem(A,b)
    % Algebraic EQs solver
    % A ... matrix
    % b ... right side vector
    % x ... solution of the algebraic EQs
    if det(A)==0
       error('!')
    end
    x = A\b; % solution
    % x = inv(A)*b; % Another possibility to obtain a solution
end
```

Comment: "Can someone check if my code is correct?" is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. _You_ need to tell us if your code is correct and if it isn't, what _specifically_ it does wrong. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Also provide a [mre] within your question after you have done some debugging -- questions on SO must be self-contained and not depend on outside links to be answerable. Some helpful links [here](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
 and 
[here](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: To elaborate on what I mean when I say "do some debugging": step through your code; observe how each line of executed code affects your program; compare your intermediate results with the results you expect to see; work backwards from there to try and identify what part of your program causes your intermediate results to diverge from their expected values.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am sorry. Everything should be fine now, I updated the question and tried to describe my problems with an implicit method implementation - the behavior of temperature solved implicitly randomly changes based on the given "dx" and "dt", while the explicit method is more-or-less consistent.

Comment: The construction of the linear system and where that might lead to wrong results should be discussed on scicomp.SE or on math.SE.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I will try my luck there, thanks.